# Is there a way to use seizeTransporter through AnyLogic to carry a number of agents?

Tags: anylogic, agent-based-modeling

Is there a way to use seizeTransporter through AnyLogic to carry a number of agents? For instance, board a number of passengers onto an elevator and take them to the upper floors!
In a high-rise construction project, TransporterFleet blocks are used as hoists to move workers and materials, but SeizeTransporter cannot carry number of workers to upper floors?
Is there any way to resolve this problem?
I need to drop off different number of workers in their destinations not a single agent.

I tried to use seize block and also batch and unbatch but seize can't recognize TransporterFleet as its resourcePool!!!

Comment: you batch, then you seize the transporter

Comment: Hey Flippe,
When I used Seize block instead of SeizeTransporter block, it didn't recognize TransporterFleet as a resource pool. 
It seems to me that AnyLogic does not have an option for moving pedestrian agents except a single agent, in levels like workers or passengers as part of a transporter fleet like elevators or hoists.
When I used batch and unbath plus seizeTransporter (not seize block), the block doesn't work.
To achieve those objectives, I need to simulate most real-life lifting processes in high-rise buildings using hoists and track number of workers boarding and unboarding.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to guide me.

Answer (score 0):

As Felipe mentionned, use `Batch`/`Unbatch` to group agents together.
`TransporterFleet` is part of the MHL and will only work with its related blocks. Instead of `Seize`, use either `SeizeTransporter` or `MoveByTransporter`, whichever applies.

Comment: Hi,

As I said above, I used batch and unbatch plus seizeTransporter. I need to simulate real-world lifting processes in high-rise buildings using hoists and track number of workers boarding and unboarding. Since the seizeTransporter only carries one agent, how can I show some workers unboarding on some floors and boarding on others?

Comment: If you want that level of granularity, with differing amounts of agents entering and exiting at every stop, you might want to look into "agentifying" your elevator. Then you could play with agent populations, moving them into/out of your agentyfied elevator.